# Add N months to YYYY-MM date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function that adds `N months` to the `YYYY-MM` date.

Wonder if it could be written better, cleaner, without then need to handle the special case when `months == 0`? I'm not looking for some JS library function that would do that, I'm interested in the algorithm itself.

```js
function add_months(time, months_to_add) {
  const mcount = time.month + months_to_add
  let years    = time.year + Math.floor(mcount / 12)
  let months   = mcount % 12
  if (months == 0) {
    years  -= 1
    months = 12
  }
  return { years, months }
}

console.log([
  add_months({ year: 2001, month: 1 }, 2),
  add_months({ year: 2001, month: 11 }, 1)
])
```

Comment: Opinion based questions are discouraged on SO. You should only ask questions for a specific problem. You might get more help with this  at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main challenge is due to the fact that we count months between 1 and 12, while a modulo of 12 have a valid range of 0 to 11.

We can solve this by first subtracting 1 from the month count so that its range can fit within the modulo's range, and add the 1 back after the modulo calculation.

```js
function addMonths(time, monthsToAdd) {
  const offsetCycles = Math.ceil(Math.abs(monthsToAdd) / 12);
  const zeroBasedMonth = time.month + monthsToAdd - 1 + offsetCycles * 12;
  const additionalYears = Math.floor(zeroBasedMonth / 12) - offsetCycles;

  return {
    year: time.year + additionalYears,
    month: (zeroBasedMonth % 12) + 1,
  };
}

console.log([
  addMonths({ year: 2001, month: 1 }, 2),
  addMonths({ year: 2001, month: 11 }, 2),
  addMonths({ year: 2001, month: 11 }, 1),
  addMonths({ year: 2001, month: 11 }, 12),
  addMonths({ year: 2001, month: 11 }, 14),
  addMonths({ year: 2001, month: 1 }, -1),
  addMonths({ year: 2001, month: 1 }, -13),
]);
```

However, I am not sure whether it is worthwhile to eliminate the `if` block like this.

Comment: Thanks, but it produces the wrong result, `addMonths({ year: 2001, month: 11 }, 2)` would produce `{ months: 13, years: 2001 }`

Comment: @AlexCraft Yes, you are right. I updated the answer to correct the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JS [`date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)?

```js
function add_months(time, months_to_add) {
  let date = new Date(time.year, time.month, 0);
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months_to_add);
  
  return [ date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() ];
}

console.log([
  add_months({ year: 2001, month: 1 }, 2),
  add_months({ year: 2001, month: 11 }, 1)
])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, but I'm also interested in the algorithm itself, just curious if the logic could be simplified. :)

Comment: If the question is only about the improvement of the logic, and not 'to find a better way', you should ask on [codereview.se] as @mandulaj suggested.